# How to format code in visual assist X

Tags: c++, visual-studio, resharper, visual-assist

How to format (clean UP) C++ code in visual assist X 10.
I'm using Resharper to clean up the code. but the shortcut doesn't work for c++ files.

does this feature exist in visual assist X 10?

Answer (score 0):

This might be somewhat off to your question as it does not involve Visual Assist, but I find [AStyle Extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2f3f04cd-2866-4e47-a671-d1cc9cc3fb02) as an excellent tool for formatting my source code in C++.